# How to validate zipcode using regular expression?

Tags: regex, oracle

How to validate zipcode using regular expression?

It should be in the following pattern:-

```
[A-z][0-9][A-Z] [0-9][A-Z][0-9]
```

E.g.

```
B5D 2M4 
b5d 2m4
```

I am using Oracle9i.

Thanks in advance,
Shubhojwal Ghosh

Comment: The pattern looks like [A-Z][0-9][A-Z] [0-9][A-Z][0-9] [a-z][0-9][a-z] [0-9][a-z][0-9]

Comment: [A-Z] is only matching upper case, [a-z] only matches lower case. Try [a-zA-Z] to match both.

Comment: Also assuming that every single person using your application conforms to that format of zipcode - no possibility of foreign addresses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, since you are using a very old version of Oracle, you cannot use the standard regular expression functions like `REGEXP_LIKE`.  If you were to upgrade to a moderately recent version of Oracle, that would be the way to go.

In older versions of Oracle, you would have to use the [`OWA_PATTERN`](http://www.stanford.edu/dept/itss/docs/oracle/10g/appdev.101/b10802/w_patt.htm) package.  Note that since the `OWA_PATTERN.MATCH` function returns a `BOOLEAN`, you cannot call it from SQL, just from PL/SQL.  You could, of course, create your own wrapper function that returns an integer or a string to indicate whether the ZIP code is valid.

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  declare
  2    function is_valid_zip( p_zip_code in varchar2 )
  3      return boolean
  4    is
  5    begin
  6      return owa_pattern.match( p_zip_code,
  7                                '[A-Z]{1}\d{1}[A-Z]{1}\d{1}[A-Z]{1}\d{1}',
  8                                'i' );
  9    end is_valid_zip;
 10  begin
 11    if( is_valid_zip( 'A1B2C3' ) )
 12    then
 13      p.l( '1) Match' );
 14    else
 15      p.l( '1) No match' );
 16    end if;
 17    if( is_valid_zip( '12345' ) )
 18    then
 19      p.l( '2) Match' );
 20    else
 21      p.l( '2) No match' );
 22    end if;
 23* end;
SQL> /
1) Match
2) No match

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```